# A more elegant way of adding option data to a dropdown box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I have below is currently what I am wanting to see if I can shorten. The code works as-is right now but I don't like the face that each IF statement has its own **$each loop** in it. **`I was wanting to see if I can condensed this down`** to allow only one call to the **$each loop**.

```
switch (input.Type.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'slider':
        .....[skipped code here]
    case 'ddl':
       inputContainer.append($("<select>")
         .attr("id", input.ID)
         .addClass("ctrl")
         .addClass("form-item-ddl")
       );

       if (input.TextField.toLowerCase() == 'gender') {
           $.each(input.Data,
               function(i, item) {
                   $("#" + input.ID).append($('<option>', {
                       value: item.code,
                       text: item.gender
                   }));
           });
       } else if (input.TextField.toLowerCase() == 'race') {
            $.each(input.Data,
                function(i, item) {
                    $("#" + input.ID).append($('<option>', {
                        value: item.code,
                        text: item.race
                    }));
            });
       } else if (input.TextField.toLowerCase() == 'pob') {
            $.each(input.Data,
                function(i, item) {
                    $("#" + input.ID).append($('<option>', {
                         value: item.code,
                         text: item.pob
                }));
            });
       } else if (input.TextField.toLowerCase() == 'name') {
            $.each(input.Data,
                function(i, item) {
                    $("#" + input.ID).append($('<option>', {
                         value: item.code,
                         text: item.name
                    }));
            });
       } else if (input.TextField.toLowerCase() == 'color') {
            $.each(input.Data,
                function(i, item) {
                    $("#" + input.ID).append($('<option>', {
                         value: item.code,
                         text: item.color
                    }));
                });
       }

       break;
     case 'checkbox':
        ...[skipped code here]
```

Take note that the **`text: item.****`** can be **gender**, **race**, **pob**, **name** and **color**. The **`value: item.code`** stays the same for all of them.

So can this be shortened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to reference the correct item depending on the content of `input.TextField`  eg `text: item[input.TextField.toLowerCase()]`

That way you only need test if input is a valid option. You can use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to hold the types and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the item is in the array.

Thus your code becomes

```
switch (input.Type.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'slider':
        .....[skipped code here]
    case 'ddl':
        inputContainer.append(
           $("<select>")
               .attr("id", input.ID)
               .addClass("ctrl")
               .addClass("form-item-ddl")
        );
        const name = input.TextField.toLowerCase();
        const valid = ["gender", "race", "job", "name", "color"].includes(name);
        const $e = $("#" + input.ID);
        const addItem = (i, it) => {$e.append($('<option>',{value: it.code, text: it[name]}))}; 
        valid && $.each(input.Data, addItem);
        
        break;
     case 'checkbox':
        ...[skipped code here]
```